# Variable TT is not defined: Error in OpenBUGS

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, r2winbugs, openbugs

I am trying to run a model in OpenBUGS. But I am getting an error "Variable TT is not defined". Here is my BUGS code:

```
model{
   for(t in 2:TT){
    for(i in 1:N){
y[t,i] ~ dmnorm(y1[t,i], tau[i])
     } 
y1[t,1] <- (p[1,1] * y[t-1,1]) + (p[1,2] *y[t-1,2]) + (p[1,3] *y[t-1,3])
y1[t,2] <- (p[2,1] * y[t-1,1]) + (p[2,2] *y[t-1,2]) + (p[2,3] *y[t-1,3])
y1[t,3] <- (p[3,1] * y[t-1,1]) + (p[3,2] *y[t-1,2]) + (p[3,3] *y[t-1,3])
  }
    for (s1 in 1:N) {
        for (s2 in 1:N) {
        p[s1, s2]~ dnorm(1, 1)
                         }
                      }
for(i in 1:N){
tau[i] ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
             }    
}
```

Here is my data and R code to run the BUGS code:

```
Data=structure(.Data=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6), .Dim=c(5,3))
TT=nrow(Data)
N=ncol(Data)
y=as.matrix(Data)
sp.data = list(y, N, TT)

Sp.sim0<- bugs (sp.data, inits=NULL, 
           parameters=c('p'),  model.file= "model2.txt",n.chains=2,  DIC=TRUE,n.iter=1000, codaPkg=FALSE,debug=TRUE)
```

Can any please help to t solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927118/passing-variable-to-winbugs-model-in-r. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Data should add as: sp.data = list(y=y, N=N, TT=TT). Thanks Andrew Cheong